# Can the upper and lower critical dimensionalities of a model coincide?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, statistical-mechanics, condensed-matter, field-theory, string-theory

Is it possible for a field theory to have the same upper and lower critical dimensions? Has this ever been observed in any model (be it condensed matter, statistical mechanics, QFT, string etc.)?